# search begin string and search end string then print all lines between begin to end lines in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have variable output "var1" like below.

```
load: load1
a: apples
b: banana
c: oranges
d: grapes

load: load2
a: pen
b: paper
c: books
```

What i want is find first string that is "load: load1" and find last string
  "d: grapes" and print the lines below lines.

```
load: load1
a: apples
b: banana
c: oranges
d: grapes
```

To serve this purpose i was using "begin" and "end" commands. How get it done using python?

Comment: write how your variable looks like exactly: is it a string or dictionary

Comment: also provide your code

Comment: its variable and i will get from command output

Comment: Any reason not to just `var1.split('\n\n')`?

Comment: The reason is i will provide portion of  lines  as input to another command. Since i dont want to provide all the variable var1 output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like (assuming you're loading from a file):

```
start_line = "load: load1"
end_line = "d: grapes"
print_lines = False

with open('input.txt' , 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line == start_line:
            print_lines = True
        if print_lines:
            print line
        if line == end_line:
            print_lines = False
            # Could add a break here if you wanted to do nothing with 
            # the rest of the file; e.g:
            # break
```

Comment: Working, Thanks a lot